# View is rendered before user type is loaded from firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

So I'm building an Ionic - Angular app that have an hospital patient submit a request to the nurse stuff and the nurse stuff can see their assigned requests (based on the room that assigned to the patient submitting the request). A nurse can see all requests and a patient can see only his/her requests. I have a function in the auth.service.ts that is called (setUserType() ) once a user is logged in manually or if it is an auto login(token is stored and found) and fetch the user type and name once it finished authentication.

The problem is, in the my-requests.page.ts in NgOnInit I call a function in the requests service that run a query to fetch all requests(if it is a nurse) or to fetch only the user's requests(if it is a patient) based on the user type I assigned once login/auto login occured. This field is unassigned once the my-requests.page.html is rendered and I can't seem to find a way to make it render only after I have the user type information.

setUserType() function:

```
    let userId: string;
    this.userIdObservable.subscribe(x => {
      userId = x;
    });
    const userQuery = this.firestore.doc<Users>(`added-users/${userId}`);
    userQuery.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
      this._userType = x.type;
      this._userName = x.name;
    });
```

My requests ngOnInit function:

```
      ngOnInit() {
    this.segment.value = 'progress';
    this.requestSubscription = this.requestsService
      .loadRequests()
      .subscribe(requests => {
        this.requestsList = requests;
      });
  }
```

Now all the auth functions -

Auth page Authenticate function:

```
    authenticate(email: string, password: string) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.loadingCtrl
      .create({
        keyboardClose: true,
        message: 'Logging in...'
      })
      .then(loadingEl => {
        loadingEl.present();
        let authObs: Observable<AuthResponseData>;
        if (this.isLogin) {
          authObs = this.authService.login(email, password);
        } else {
          authObs = this.authService.signup(email, password);
        }
        authObs.subscribe(resData => {
          console.log(resData);
          this.isLoading = false;
          loadingEl.dismiss();
          this.authService.setUserType();
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/requests/tabs/add-requests');
        }, errRes => {
          loadingEl.dismiss();
          const code = errRes.error.error.message;
          let message = 'Could not sign you up, please try again.';
          if (code === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
            message = 'This Id exists already!';
          } else if (code === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND') {
            message = 'No such user.';
          } else if (code === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
            message = 'Could not log you in, please try again.';
          }
          this.showAlert(message);
        });
      });
  }
```

Auth service login function:

```
      login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http
      .post<AuthResponseData>(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=${
          environment.firebaseAPIKey
        }`,
        { email: email, password: password, returnSecureToken: true }
      )
      .pipe(tap(this.setUserData.bind(this)));
  }
```

Auth service autologin function:

```
    autoLogin() {
    return from(Plugins.Storage.get({ key: 'authData' })).pipe(
      map(storedData => {
        if (!storedData || !storedData.value) {
          return null;
        }
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData.value) as {
          token: string;
          tokenExpirationDate: string;
          userId: string;
          email: string;
        };
        const expirationTime = new Date(parsedData.tokenExpirationDate);
        if (expirationTime <= new Date()) {
          return null;
        }
        const user = new User(
          parsedData.userId,
          parsedData.email,
          parsedData.token,
          expirationTime
        );
        return user;
      }),
      tap(user => {
        if (user) {
          this._user.next(user);
          this.setUserType();
        }
      }),
      map(user => {
        return !!user;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why are you subscribing to string userId and then assigning it in the subscribe method?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is a bad name setting decision made by me. this.userId is a getter that return an observable that holds the user information after it got the id from firestore.

Comment: Please change and update the question

Comment: I updated the code and added an update summary. Sorry for that, I'm quite new here and new to Angular as well

Comment: You can create separate service that you include in root with logged in information stored in a behaviour subject and then subscribe it in your component and make call when you have data there. Include this service only at root level.

Comment: I’m not sure how to do it really and where is root? App.component? Can you write some code ? This will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do you dont have to include it in any module cli will do that for you.

```js
import {Component, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserStateService {
  private user = new BehaviorSubject({
    isLoggedIn: false,
    userType: null
  });

  constructor() {
  }

  setUser(user) {
    this.user.next(user);
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }
}

// my request 

@Component({
  selector: 'request-component',
  templateUrl: './request-component.html'
})
export class RequestComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private userStateService: UserStateService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userStateService
      .getUser()
      .subscribe(
      ((val: {isLoggedIn: boolean, userType: any}) => {
        // calll you service
      }));
  }
}

// in your auto login or login you call setter

this.userStateService.setUser({isLoggedIn: true, userType: 'data from login'});
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort of writing all of this! I tried to implement it but the things is, when I want to use it in my login or auto login, I need to send the BehaviourSubject the userType which I don't have. In order to send it the userType, I need to query the firestore users collection based on the userId in the authrization table (each user's id in my users collection has the same user authrization's id). When I log in it seems to get the user type as needed but when I refresh, it loses it.

Comment: Then you need to save it in the local storage.